# Express session not saving / persisting

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, express, express-session

I'm not sure what I did wrong
Last project before this was fine, session is saving / persisting

Stack: MEAN
Node version: v14.15.0
Express version: v4.17.1
Express session version: v1.17.2

app.ts

```js
// ...
_session: typeof expressSession = require('express-session')
/* Session Store */; this.session_store = new MongoStore({ mongoUrl: this.dbURL });
        this.session = this._session({
            secret: this.keys,
            store: this.session_store,
            saveUninitialized: false,
            resave: true,
            cookie: {
                path: '/',
                httpOnly: true,
                secure: false,
                maxAge: 1 * 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 12 hours
            },
            rolling: true
        })
// ...
/* Config */; require('./config.ts');
```

config.ts

```js
// ...
/* Session Middleware */; app.use((request, response, next) => APP.session(request, response, next));
// ...
```

login.ts

```js
app.post("/api/login", async (request, response) => {
    let body = request.body,
        username: string = body.username,
        password: string = body.password,
        db_account = APP.db.collection("accounts");

    if ((!username || !password)) {
        if (!request.session["_register"]) return response.sendStatus(411)
        username = request.session["_register"].username
        password = request.session["_register"].password
        // request.session["_register"] = undefined
    }
    // validator check
    if (!validator.isAlphanumeric(username) && !validator.isEmail(username)) return response.status(400).send("username")

    // find DB, either username or email
    const docs = await db_account.find({ $or: [{ username: username }, { email: username }] }).toArray()

    // Not found
    if (!docs.length) return response.status(404).json({ error: "username" })

    let account: Account = docs[0] as any
    if (password != account.password) return response.status(401).json({ error: "password" })

    request.session["auth"] = username
    console.log(request.session["auth"]) // username attribute exist at this point
    return response.status(200).json({ error: null })
})

app.post('/api/auth', async (request, response) => {
    console.log(request.session["auth"]); // undefined

    request.session["auth"]
        ? response.send({ auth: true })
        : response.send({ auth: false })
})
```

Front end side
login.component.ts

```js
  async login() {
    if (this.password.invalid || this.username.invalid) return;

    let res: any = await lastValueFrom(this.http.post(server_host() + "/api/login", {
      username: this.username.value,
      password: md5(this.password),
    }))
      .catch(err => {
        if (err)
          return alert("Something went wrong. Please refresh the page and try again.")
      })

    if (res && !res.error) {
      localStorage.setItem("auth", "true")
      return this.router.navigate([''])
    }
    return alert("Something went wrong. Please refresh the page and try again.")
  }
```

Front end middleware
app.component.ts

```js
  async auth(): Promise<boolean> {
    if (!localStorage.getItem('auth')) return false
    var res = await lastValueFrom(this.http.post(server_host() + "/api/auth", {}, { withCredentials: true })) as any;
    if (!res.auth) { localStorage.removeItem("auth"); return false }
    return true
  }

// ...
      if (ev instanceof NavigationStart) {
        //Middleware
        this.loading = true;
        await this.auth();
      }
// ...
```

On previous project, following more or less same template / work logic, it works as intended (session persisting / saving)
Where did I go wrong?

EDIT:
found a way to see all active session
[View all currently active sessions in express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018761/view-all-currently-active-sessions-in-express-js)

so I tried to do this

```js
app.post('/api/auth', async (request, response) => {
    (request as any).sessionStore.all((err: Error, sessions: any) => {
        console.log(sessions);
    })
    
    console.log(request.session["auth"]); // still undefined

    request.session["auth"]
        ? response.send({ auth: true })
        : response.send({ auth: false })
})
```

I got this output:

```js
undefined // from console.log(request.session["auth"]);
[
  {
    cookie: {
      originalMaxAge: 43200000,
      expires: '2022-03-21T18:14:12.367Z',
      secure: false,
      httpOnly: true,
      path: '/'
    },
    auth: 'person'
  },
  {
    cookie: {
      originalMaxAge: 43200000,
      expires: '2022-03-21T18:16:04.345Z',
      secure: false,
      httpOnly: true,
      path: '/'
    },
    auth: 'person'
  },
  {
    cookie: {
      originalMaxAge: null,
      expires: null,
      secure: false,
      httpOnly: true,
      path: '/'
    },
    auth: 'person1'
  },
// the list goes on...
]
```

meaning the session IS SAVED but received request is using different session / cookie?
I'm not sure what's wrong here, I'm using Angular (MEAN stack)

Answer (score 0):

"received request is using different session / cookie?"

To my understanding, I see that it creates a new cookie/session each time it logins, in other words, it creates a login token that lasts for 12h EACH time when you login, should probably fix that, as it seems that it doesn't overwrite the old ones, or at least replace them.

Comment: hi! thx for your reply! i dont get what to fix as i dont know why it creates a new cookie / session each time i login. can you please enlighten me on this?

Comment: Well at 'app.ts' you literally create a new session each time a login is made/successful. 
You need to use a method to check IF an session already exists for that user and if it does then retrieve it instead of initializing a new one.

Comment: which part of app.ts are you talking about? do you mean the login.ts or...?

Comment: Avoiding the obv. are we? I clearly I mentioned the 'app.ts', which is the first thing in your post.

Comment: can you highlight which part of the code you're talking about?

Comment: **/* Session Store */; this.session_store = new MongoStore({ mongoUrl: this.dbURL });** and then you **store: this.session_store,**. You are creating a new session for each login/connection and even the cookies, but instead you should be checking and getting the already existing ones. Hence pseudo code: **if(session(<SOME FORM OF USER IDENTIFICATION>).Exists()) { */Retrieve the existing session and NOT create cookies/* } else { */Create a new 'empty' session and cookies, then write stuff there when the user logins. (But you're doing this regardless every time in your current code./* }**